# Dynamic table values from array of objects in react 17.0.01

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of object in the below format.

```
[0: {Number: "11080", Cost1: "354", Cost2: "354", Cost3: "354", quantity: "2000"}]
```

How do show this array of objects inside a table

Here is my required table structure  - https://jsfiddle.net/deepakmurthy/Lhv2sk9d/

```
 {
      newFilteredArray?.map((value) => {
          return(
              <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>{quantity}</td>
              <td>{Cost}</td>
              <td>xxx</td>
              <td>xxx</td>
              <td>xxx</td>
              <td>xxx</td>
              </tr>
          );
  })
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: 3 rows of cost1, cost2 and cost3 should be generated, where in my case i am getting only one row

Comment: The array only has one item? Why would it output more than one row?

Comment: I need cost1 in one row and cost2 in one row and cost3 in another row

Comment: So output three rows per map iteration

Comment: yes, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have more data in your array you might consider refactoring it before mapping, but as James mentioned in the comments you can simply add three rows per iteration.

The example below isolates the `Cost{n}` properties using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), then maps the `Object.keys()` to return one row per key.

```
{
  data.map(({ Number, quantity, ...costs }) => {
    return (Object.keys(costs).map(key => (
      <tr>
        <td>{key}</td>
        <td>{quantity}</td>
        <td>{costs[key]}</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
      </tr>))
    )
  })
}
```

---

```js
const App = () => {

  const data = [{ Number: "11080", Cost1: "354", Cost2: "354", Cost3: "354", quantity: "2000" }]

  return (
    <table className="table table-striped bsictable" border="1" style={{ border: '#cdcdcd solid 1px' }}>
      <thead>
        <tr align="center">
          <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
          <th colspan="2">New </th>
          <th colspan="2">Pending</th>
          <th colspan="2">Completed </th>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Cost</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          data.map(({ Number, quantity, ...costs }) => {
            return (Object.keys(costs).map(key => (
              <tr>
                <td>{key}</td>
                <td>{quantity}</td>
                <td>{costs[key]}</td>
                <td>xxx</td>
                <td>xxx</td>
                <td>xxx</td>
                <td>xxx</td>
              </tr>))
            )
          })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table >
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How do i refactor before mapping ? I might be having more data in the array

Comment: It really just depends on the shape of your data, but probably grouped by Cost1, Cost2, etc.